# Control a serial device (like usb printer) from an Android app

Tags: android, usb, hardware, adb

I have two questions about Linux Android.

In the documentation it says:

"Android Debug Bridge (adb) is a versatile command line tool that lets you communicate with an emulator instance or connected Android-powered device."

And apparently there is a way to send a command to serial port (USB) from ADB (Android).

So, I need to send commands (like AT commands) from android device to usb device (printer)

1) The ADB will be present on a real device with android?, which version?

2) is there another alternative?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need an Android device with USB host mode, and to write code within an application package against the USB host API which performs the required operations.

Answer (score 1):

> And apparently there is a way to send a command to serial port (USB) from ADB (Android).

Not that I am aware of.

> The ADB will be present on a real device with android?

`adb` is a program that is part of the Android SDK. It runs on your development machine. It does not run on the emulator. It does not run on the device.

> is there another alternative?

Use the [USB APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html) and the [Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html), perhaps.

Comment: I discover this article: http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/ from @JamesWard, and I was trying to do a configurable connection, the input from AIR to Java is possible, but the return is not still.

Comment: Thanks i will seek more about this API